# Android java make two similar for loops into one loop

Tags: java, android, for-loop, view, android-view

Im trying to merge these two for loops together so that i can use it for one fillview.

Ive been trying to try for a few days but am unsure how to do this so would appreciate some help!

Any help is appreciated

```
    int maxDataSetSize = Math.max(data1.size(), Math.max(data2.size(), data3.size())) ;

    for (int i = 0; i < maxDataSetSize; i++) {
        String dataset1Value = data1.size() > i ? data1.get(i) : null;
        String dataset2Value = data2.size() > i ? data2.get(i) : null;
        String dataset3Value = data3.size() > i ? data3.get(i) : null;

        View statsRowview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.stats_row, null);

        fillView(statsRowview, dataset1Value, dataset2Value, dataset3Value);

        tableStats.addView(statsRowview);
    }


    int maxDataSetSize2 = Math.max(data4.size(), Math.max(data5.size(), data6.size()));
    for (int i = 0; i < maxDataSetSize2; i++) {
        String dataset4Value = data4.size() > i ? data4.get(i) : DEFAULT_COLOR;
        String dataset5Value = data5.size() > i ? data5.get(i) : DEFAULT_COLOR;
        String dataset6Value = data6.size() > i ? data6.get(i) : DEFAULT_COLOR;

        View statsRowview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.stats_row, null);

        fillView2(statsRowview, dataset4Value, dataset5Value, dataset6Value);

        tableStats.addView(statsRowview);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your loops read different data, call different fill methods, and will iterate through their code a different number of times.  Why on earth would you want to try to merge them?

Comment: As whats happening is this http://puu.sh/fMfrt/03a298d2ee.png, but i thought if i merge it, it would come like this: http://puu.sh/fMfxx/bb5389687f.png

Comment: I can understand it feels naturally to unify control code. But most of the time there is no good way in java to do that. It does not have macros or similiar construct needed for that (so you can only use a pattern like visitor, iterator or streams()). In the specific sample I think there is reasonable less control code in the loop construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
int maxDataSetSize = Math.max(data1.size(), Math.max(data2.size(), data3.size())) ;
int maxDataSetSize2 = Math.max(data4.size(), Math.max(data5.size(), data6.size()));

for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < maxDataSetSize || j < maxDataSetSize2; i++, j++) {

    View statsRowview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.stats_row, null);

    if(i < maxDataSetSize){
        String dataset1Value = data1.size() > i ? data1.get(i) : null;
        String dataset2Value = data2.size() > i ? data2.get(i) : null;
        String dataset3Value = data3.size() > i ? data3.get(i) : null;
        fillView(statsRowview, dataset1Value, dataset2Value, dataset3Value);
    }


    if(j < maxDataSetSize2){
        String dataset4Value = data4.size() > j ? data4.get(j) : DEFAULT_COLOR;
        String dataset5Value = data5.size() > j ? data5.get(j) : DEFAULT_COLOR;
        String dataset6Value = data6.size() > j ? data6.get(j) : DEFAULT_COLOR;
        fillView2(statsRowview, dataset4Value, dataset5Value, dataset6Value);
    }

    tableStats.addView(statsRowview);
}
```

This should work.

Comment: i guess you can call the same fillView method twice, assuming that the parameters are of the same datatype

Comment: Actually, you've solved all my problems haha owe you one! cheers

Comment: Done :) It looked so easy i almost got it once all i was missing was the && ahah you saved my life from stress :D

Comment: @user3411002: I just realized something: instead of `&&`, you should use `||`, otherwise the `for` loop will end before iterating through all values. See the edited answer.

Comment: Ah okay ill get that changed now. So with the && it would not go through the whole list?

Comment: Yes, with `&&` if either of the conditions (with `i` or `j`) failed, the `for` loop would come to a halt. But with `||` it would properly iterate through all values. I have made one more change, please see the edited answer :)